# Sector capitals not showing up as part of a sector

Tags: technical-issues, stellaris

I was playing some Stellaris and I noticed that one of my sectors had nothing in it. Turns out that most of my sector capitals had been identified as not being in one. I don't know if this is just visual, or is actually affected their bonuses, but is there any way to fix this?

[image: Outliner of my empire]

Note: This is not just in my outliner, the planet screen for them lets me create new sectors as if they were not in one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what caused it, but I found out how to fix it.

What you need to do is go to the sector section and delete all of your sectors. Then you need one by one add the sectors back again. When they come back they should all be in the right place.